# How do I update SSIS package on the server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, bids

I have updated the package in BIDS 2005 (I changed the backup routine to save to a different drive) and now I'm trying to get it back on the server (2005).  I tried File > Save Copy As...  Then ran the job that executes the package and it's still saving to the old drive, thus, my package didn't get saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion always create a deployment utility with your SSIS Project.  This is configured under the Project Properties (see below).  Once you have configured the project deployment utility, go to your project, find the "bin" folder and double-click the deployment utility.  I will  walk you through getting your package(s) onto the server really easily.

[image: SSIS Project Properties]

Good Luck!

Comment: Navigated to the bin folder and all I see are my packages in there - no utility.

Comment: You need to go into the project properties and make sure "Create Deployment Utility" is set to "True" as is shown in the picture above.

Comment: I did that, then I selected build.  It seemed as though it worked but the package didn't back up my transaction logs to the right place.  I'm starting to think that maybe there is something wrong with the package itself.  All it does is backup transaction logs and the only difference is that they are going to a different drive.  There is a Back Up Database Task and I changed the drive letter to the new drive.  Then I did as I said above and the files are still going to the old drive...

Comment: Got it, I had to actually move the package to the server and deploy it from there - I think I was unable to because my workstation is win 7 and the DB is on server 2003.

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty answer is to use [dtutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162820.aspx)

```
dtutil /file C:\Src\MyPackage.dtsx /destserver thatDatabase /COPY SQL;MyPackage
```

I too am a fan of the manifest files but, while probably overkill for your problem, I prefer to use tools that allow for unattended use. I combine the ssisdeploymanifest with a PowerShell script to handle all of SSIS deployments.

[Powershell SSIS Deployment and maintenance](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2011/08/powershell-ssis-deployment-and.html)